# How to use Recurrent Neural network for classification

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, classification, finance, chainer

I plan to use Recurrent Neural network(RNN) for finance data classification with python. I predict that market price is up, unchange or down to use RNN. I can't understand how to classify the label.

I refer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129411/how-can-recurrent-neural-networks-be-used-for-sequence-classification ,but I can't program these theory to use python with Library:chainer. Are there any sources to refer?